# thread.join() does not work when target function uses subprocess.run()

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function that runs another function in the background as a command line using subprocess.run(). When this function runs generates as many processes as I gave as input. For instance:

```
# Importing libraries
import subprocess
import threading

# Function with background function inside
def func(input_value, processes):

    # Running background function as many times as processes I input
    for i in range(processes)
       subprocess.run("nohup python3 func_background " + input_value + "&\n", shell= True)
```

So if I specify 50, I will run 50 processes in the background with the same input value. The problem is that now I am trying to run different input_values with many processes each of them. Of course If I run all input values at the same time I will max up the CPU, so I was trying to create one thread for each input value and run one by one waiting for each new thread to finish until I run the next (using thread.join()). Like this:

```
# Defining in input values
list_input_values = [input_value_1, input_value_2]

# Looping over input values creating one thread with each of them
for i in list_input_values:

  # Creating thread
  th = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(i,4))
  # Starting thread an trying to make the loop wait to start a new one
  th.deamon = True
  th.start()
  th.join()
```

This works, but it runs both threads instead of one by one and I don't know if its because of the loop or because the target function that I specify finishs but the subprocess.run() inside no. Is there any way to solve this by waiting for the background function to finish or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Re, "trying to create one thread for each [...and then] waiting for each new thread to finish [before] I run the next." That makes no sense. What would be the point of creating those threads if you don't allow them to run concurrently with each other?

Comment: @SolomonSlow True, but I was trying to find a way to don't let the loop go to the next iteration until the first one is finished, because the first itration will use all the possible cores and then when they finish pass to the next iteration.

Comment: P.S., What makes you think that the `th.join()` call "does not work?" You said, "it runs both threads..." but how do you _know_ what it is doing? What output do you get, or what side effects do you see that you weren't expecting? Have you tried adding `print(...)` calls to the program to confirm your belief?

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment, not an answer. I can't include code in a comment. I asked, why create threads if you aren't going to let the threads run concurrently?

You said;

> I was trying to find a way to don't let the loop go to the next iteration until the first one is finished, beciuase the first itration will use all the possible cores and then when they finish pass to the next iteration.

OK, So why don't you just do this?

```Python
list_input_values = [input_value_1, input_value_2]
for i in list_input_values:
  func(i,4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but in my case for each interation I need the function inside of func() to run 50 times at the same time with subprocess.run(), like this func(i, 50), so 50 processes that will take all my CPU power. I wanted to run one iteration and not pass to the next until all the processes from last iteration are done.

Comment: @robertoimuno, That doesn't answer my question. Your example creates two threads that are supposed to run _one after the other,_ and call `func(i,4)`. My example simply calls `func(i,4)` two times, _one after the other._ What do you think your example can do that mine can't do? Why are you creating those threads?

Comment: Both ways work, so if I create the threads they both run at the same time and generate the output I want, and If i run your example it works the same but without having to create threads. The problem is that if I do func(i, 4) with the to input values of the loops is fine becuase each time func runs I generate 4 processes, but I need to run func with 50 or more, also I have more than 2 input values and I was trying to find a way to make the loop wait until there is free cores to run the processes. I was using threads because i thought it was a way to do that but actually is not.

Comment: Re, "I was trying to find a way to make the loop wait until there is free cores to run the processes." Sorry, I don't know how to help with that, but I'm pretty sure that creating and joining threads is not the way.